# Simple Gradient Descent Project plausibility

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am currently in a numerical analysis class at my university and wanted to tackle a project applying gradient descent. Fair warning: I am new to machine learning, but my professor believed in me, so I had trouble saying no. Please bare with me and correct me wherever possible. I really would appreciate some guidance from you guys!

The idea they gave me was to estimate a family of functions, specifically cubics by applying gradient descent on the loss function which will be least squares. I can start with some cubic so I know the outputs/labels.

So from my understanding our hypothesis is $h(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{3}\alpha_kx^k$?

Our loss function is $L(h(x),f(x))=(h(x_i)-f(x_i))^2$. My professor said it would be best to use the emperical error $L(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}L(h(x_i),f(x_i))$ where $\theta = [\alpha_k]_{k=0}^{3}$ and we apply the gradient descent algorithm to find $\theta^\star=\arg\min L(\theta)$.

So I believe the idea is,

1. Have some known cubic with some gaussian noise.
2. Initiate a cubic with random weights.
3. Calculate the gradients of the least squares for each coefficient/weight.
4. Apply gradient descent to $L(\theta)$ and find the optimal weights?

Question 1: In general cubics are not convex. I need to explain why the method works and most of assumptions rely on having a convex function. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Question 2: Why is the emperical error method a good idea here?

Question/comment 3: Least squares is tripping me up, from my perspective it is no different than MSE, as it seems very similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you outlined in bullet points 1-4 is correct. Although a cubic is not convex in general, it wouldn't matter even if this was a 100-degree polynomial because this is actually a *linear regression*, and with mean squared error (MSE) as the loss function, it's a convex problem.

Empirical error is the error you calculate using the data you have, so when learning from data, I don't see another option here.

As wikipedia says:

> The method of least squares is a standard approach in regression
> analysis to approximate the solution of overdetermined systems (sets
> of equations in which there are more equations than unknowns) by
> minimizing the sum of the squares of the residuals made in the results
> of every single equation.

Least squares is the name of the method, but MSE is the loss function used.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. This has cleared many doubts.